# Keep a global variable static - python

Tags: python, variables, global, local

I thought I understood global and local variables, but apparently not. Similar questions seem to hinge around altering a global variable, however mine is being altered and it shouldn't be.

I have a list with some numbers in and I want to use these numbers to create a new list, without altering the initial list.

```
deductions = 3
gross = [5,5,5,5]
net = net_result(gross, deductions)

def net_result(G, D):
    Nets = G
    Deduct = D
    for each in range(0,4):
        if Deduct > Nets[each]:
            Deduct = Deduct - Nets[each]
            Nets[each] = 0
        else:
            Nets[each] = Nets[each] - Deduct
            Deduct = 0
    return (Nets, Deduct)
```

In the code above, the output for net is correct but then gross is also being reduced at the same time. Resulting in gross and net being equal to [2,5,5,5], when it should be gross[5,5,5,5] and net[[2,5,5,5],0]

This just seems wrong to me but I can't work out what I'm not getting. Otherwise I have to reset the Gross variables or I can't call them again

Comment: You can't keep any variable static in Python (you'd need to write a C extension to truly lock down an object attribute).

Comment: `net_result(gross[:], deductions)`, copy the list, lists are mutable so any changes in the function are going to be changing the same object